# Is induced topology isometry?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am learning induced topology now. I wonder if the induced topology isometry if it is metrizable. That is to say:

if the function $f:space ~A\rightarrow space~ B$ is one to one and there is a topology $\tau_B$ on $B$ which is metrizable by the metric $d_B$. Then there is an induced topology on $A$ by $f$, denoted by $\tau_A$. I think $\tau_A$ is also metrizable by some metric, for example, $d_A$. Now my question is:

do we have $d_A(x,y)=d_B(f(x),f(y))$ for $x,y\in A$?

Answer (score 0):

if i got it correctly if your funtion f is an isometry from spaceA to spaceB then yes we do.
and the topology on A is indeed metrizable by a metric

Comment: thanks a lot! but could you please say anything more about how to get the isometry?